# Wordpress Posts with external API

Tags: wordpress, api

I've got a Wordpress Project where I have to include Products as Post with a external API.
This is important because they are using a merchandise management system and everything has to be synchronized. But Wordpress is the perfect Solution for all the stuff around. Also it should be possible, to send data back to this API, if someone is interested in any product.

First I tried to put the API Products into posts, but then I run into the problem, that the Database saved everything and it got more complicated.

Perfect solution would be:
Connect to Api with WP_Query and avoid the Rest API and DB of Wordpress. It is not neccessary to show the posts in the backend. It should only be remote by this API but possible to use all those wp_query and taxonomy features of posts. Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.